# .profile file linking

Tags: linux, unix

I have .profile file on my unix system. I have added some variables in another file (File Name=  .others).
And I want to link this file within .profile file. Each time I log on the system .profile and .others property files will be loaded.

How can I link between these files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to your .profile this

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.others" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.others"
fi
```

and add something to .others like this

```
export foo=bar
```

or whatever u want into .others ;)

EDIT: altough there is a easier way to do this, put the content of .others into .bashrc (at the end)

Comment: Thx. How can I find bashrc file path

Comment: it should be in $HOME if you use bash.
ls -al $HOME/.bashrc